# What kind of tree is this? ...and is it strong enough for a tree house?

Tags: trees

I want to build a tree house.

This tree has sprouted into three trunks.

The pines in the vicinity are too thin.

Is this species sufficient?

[image]

[image]

EDIT:  Leaves at base of tree.
[image]

Comment: could you do a photo on a small brunch, with a bud? (or a old leave on the ground) Where do you took the photo?

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi  Does the close up of the leaves at the base of the tree help?

Comment: This is not a close up of the leaves. You just zoomed in on the first picture.

Comment: Just from the pictures, i couldn't even guess how thick the stems are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the bark with its vertical grooves and the few leaves on the ground that are distinguishable it looks like a red oak (Quercus rubra).

Red oaks are known as reliable trees that do not readily drop branches or die back and stand their ground in high winds.

The fact that you have three growing close together is more unusual than one single trunk. A young sapling may have been cut back and sprouted three viable leaders. Check the base of the tree carefully to determine whether each is firmly anchored - that is likely where any weakness would exist.

Comment: A landscaper/aborist confirmed it is an oak